# How to get rid of anti banner systems

Tags: html, css, banner, antivirus, adblock

Some images of my website are detected as reclame and it is not. I have some vertical and horizontal images that are not banner, but are full img from my website.

Some antivirus like Kaspersky remove the display of it.

How can I force to display it and to make understand Kaspersky it is not a banner.

[image]

I've circled in orange where images should be.

Comment: Have you tweaked the image dimensions to see if any are not blocked?

Comment: all is set to 100% (responsive)

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the dimensions of the divs wrapping the images to match the size of the images and use `background-image` instead.

So instead of this:

```
<div class="someDiv">
    <img src="abcd.jpg" alt="someImage" />
</div>
```

Remove the `img` tag and add it as a background image for the div like this:

```
.someDiv {
    background-image: url('abcd.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat:none;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Tweak the `background-size` value according to what you want and you can add `background-attachment` property if you want to tweak with image attachment too.

---

Now to make the div or parts of the div clickable, you can just add transparent anchor tags and position them over different parts of the div using `position: relative;`

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities:

1) Check the class/ID names of your images and make sure they're not named with something that might be construed as an ad.

2) Check the sizes of your images and compare with standard IAB ad format sizes. eg: A 300x200 image or a 468x60 image etc are likely to be blocked.

3) Where are these images being served from? Are you serving from a directory or CDN location that is also serving ads? Are these images coming from the same domain? Are they deep-linked on another domain?

4) It's also possible that you might have specific filters on your site that are blocking specifically named DIVs or directories on your domain.

You can search for filters specifically affecting your domain at: http://blockadblock.com/search-adblock-filters.php